# Using CTE with paging to fetch records from 3 tables

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, join, common-table-expression

I have three tables TableA, TableB, TableC, and Table A have millions of records.

Table A have AccountId, table B have accountId, Client and their certificate and TableC has certificates.

The situation is that in Table B AccountId have multiple client with multiple certificates.

When I try to fetch data from table A by joining table B and C, It fetch the duplicate records because in table B AccountId have multiple client with multiple certificates.

You can use this script to populate the tables and data for test the situation

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TableA]
(
    [AccountId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Name] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [Mobile] [nchar](10) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Accounts] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [AccountId] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TableB]
(
    [Id] [int] NOT NULL,
    [ClientId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [CertificateId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [AccountId] [int] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_TableB] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC,
    [ClientId] ASC,
    [CertificateId] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TableC]
(
    [CertificateId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Status] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [Description] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_TableC] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [CertificateId] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

INSERT [dbo].[TableA] ([AccountId], [Name], [Mobile]) VALUES (1, N'John', N'98        ')
INSERT [dbo].[TableA] ([AccountId], [Name], [Mobile]) VALUES (2, N'Henry', N'9808      ')
INSERT [dbo].[TableA] ([AccountId], [Name], [Mobile]) VALUES (3, N'Paine', N'9045      ')
INSERT [dbo].[TableA] ([AccountId], [Name], [Mobile]) VALUES (4, N'Andrew', N'887       ')
INSERT [dbo].[TableA] ([AccountId], [Name], [Mobile]) VALUES (5, N'Stocks', N'78        ')
INSERT [dbo].[TableB] ([Id], [ClientId], [CertificateId], [AccountId]) VALUES (1, 5, 34, 1)
INSERT [dbo].[TableB] ([Id], [ClientId], [CertificateId], [AccountId]) VALUES (2, 8, 34, 1)
INSERT [dbo].[TableB] ([Id], [ClientId], [CertificateId], [AccountId]) VALUES (3, 7, 36, 2)
INSERT [dbo].[TableB] ([Id], [ClientId], [CertificateId], [AccountId]) VALUES (4, 9, 37, 3)
INSERT [dbo].[TableB] ([Id], [ClientId], [CertificateId], [AccountId]) VALUES (5, 10, 37, 4)
INSERT [dbo].[TableB] ([Id], [ClientId], [CertificateId], [AccountId]) VALUES (6, 4, 37, 4)
INSERT [dbo].[TableB] ([Id], [ClientId], [CertificateId], [AccountId]) VALUES (7, 61, 37, 4)
INSERT [dbo].[TableB] ([Id], [ClientId], [CertificateId], [AccountId]) VALUES (8, 45, 35, 5)
INSERT [dbo].[TableC] ([CertificateId], [Status], [Description]) VALUES (34, 1, N'Certificate 1')
INSERT [dbo].[TableC] ([CertificateId], [Status], [Description]) VALUES (35, 1, N'Certificate 2')
INSERT [dbo].[TableC] ([CertificateId], [Status], [Description]) VALUES (36, 1, N'Certificate 3')
INSERT [dbo].[TableC] ([CertificateId], [Status], [Description]) VALUES (37, 0, N'Certificate 4')
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[TableB]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_TableB_TableA] FOREIGN KEY([AccountId])
REFERENCES [dbo].[TableA] ([AccountId])
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[TableB] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_TableB_TableA]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[TableB]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_TableB_TableC] FOREIGN KEY([CertificateId])
REFERENCES [dbo].[TableC] ([CertificateId])
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[TableB] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_TableB_TableC]
GO
```

My Query

```
DECLARE @From int=1
DECLARE @To int=5
; WITH CTE_Data_WITH_PAGING  AS 
  (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER( ORDER BY A.AccountId) AS [ROW_NUMBERS], 
        A.AccountId, A.Name, A.Mobile FROM TableA A
        LEFT JOIN  TableB B  
        ON B.AccountId = A.AccountId
        INNER JOIN TableC C
        ON C.CertificateId=B.CertificateId 
        AND C.CertificateId<>01

        )
        SELECT  * FROM CTE_Data_WITH_PAGING WHERE ROW_NUMBERS BETWEEN @From AND @To;
```

[image]

I try to use distinct in this way but paging Issue.

```
SELECT DISTINCT(AccountId), Name, Mobile 
FROM CTE_Data_WITH_PAGING 
WHERE ROW_NUMBERS BETWEEN @From AND @To;
```

Paging problem: try @from=1 @to=4 and see the output.It should get AccountId: 1, 2, 3,4
[image]

Comment: I'm not clear on what the problem is.  Are you expecting the results to only have one row per customer?

Comment: What is the question?  What do your expected results look like?  Can you post sample data?

Comment: Based on the query you've provided, it's not clear why joins to TABLE B and TABLE C are even necessary.  TABLE A LEFT JOIN's to B, which means you're going to get back all rows from A, regardless of what's in B or C.

Comment: @StuartAinsworth  Yes I only fetches records from Table A, I Use table C to check certificate status and table B to map with certificateId and AccountId

Comment: Then should the LEFT join be an INNER JOIN?  Because right now, table B and table C don't affect the output (other than amplifyign the matches).  If there's no match in TABLE B, you will still get ALL rows from table A

Comment: @StuartAinsworth tried with Inner Join but the same duplicated result.

Comment: Hi. Learn what LEFT JOIN returns: INNER JOIN rows plus unmatched left table rows extended by NULLs. Always know what INNER JOIN you want as part of a LEFT JOIN. A WHERE or INNER ON that requires a right table column to be not NULL after a LEFT JOIN ON removes any rows extended by NULLs, ie leaves only INNER JOIN rows, ie "turns LEFT JOIN into INNER JOIN". You have that.

Comment: Your question does not say what you want a query to return. So how can we help you? A [mcve] includes a clear specification & desired output for given input. Is that last table supposed to be desired output?--you are not clear. Please clarify via post edits, not comments. Please [use text, not images/links, for text (including code, tables & ERDs)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097). Use a link/image only for convenience to supplement text and/or for what cannot be given in text.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A quick fix is to use dense_rank instead, combined with distinct. This makes sure that each account is counted. also use an inner join as advised in comments:

```
DECLARE @From int=1
DECLARE @To int=5
; WITH CTE_Data_WITH_PAGING  AS 
  (SELECT distinct dense_rank() OVER( ORDER BY A.AccountId) AS [ROW_NUMBERS], 
    A.AccountId, A.Name, A.Mobile FROM TableA A
    inner JOIN  TableB B  
    ON B.AccountId = A.AccountId
    INNER JOIN TableC C
    ON C.CertificateId=B.CertificateId 
    AND C.CertificateId<>01

    )
    SELECT  * FROM CTE_Data_WITH_PAGING WHERE ROW_NUMBERS BETWEEN @From AND @To;
```

I tend to prefer using group by, in stead of distinct - especially in combination  with analytical functions, so another go - using row_number could be:

```
DECLARE @From int=1
DECLARE @To int=5
; WITH CTE_Data_WITH_PAGING  AS 
  (SELECT  row_number() OVER( ORDER BY A.AccountId) AS [ROW_NUMBERS], 
    A.AccountId, A.Name, A.Mobile FROM TableA A
    inner JOIN  TableB B  
    ON B.AccountId = A.AccountId
    INNER JOIN TableC C
    ON C.CertificateId=B.CertificateId 
    AND C.CertificateId<>01
    group by  A.AccountId, A.Name, A.Mobile
    )
    SELECT  * FROM CTE_Data_WITH_PAGING WHERE ROW_NUMBERS BETWEEN @From AND @To;
```

Here I grouped by to get unique values.

Finally, if you are just in it for the paging, and do not need the row numbers, the just use OFFSET and FETCH, like this:

DECLARE @From int=1
DECLARE @To int=5

```
 SELECT  
  A.AccountId, A.Name, A.Mobile FROM TableA A
  inner JOIN  TableB B  
  ON B.AccountId = A.AccountId
  INNER JOIN TableC C
  ON C.CertificateId=B.CertificateId 
  AND C.CertificateId<>01
 group by  A.AccountId, A.Name, A.Mobile
 order by  A.AccountId
 OFFSET (@FROM-1) ROWS FETCH NEXT (@TO-(@FROM-1)) ROWS ONLY;
```

Comment: I use your solution row_number() with group by and also dense_rank one. But both having performance issue when dealing with large records. can you please suggest me how to handle this.